# Using TextAreaStyle in TextArea on android destroys native behavior (Qt/QMl)

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I am using a TextArea in a Android Qt/QML project. On default selecting text by pressing long works as expected on android (like the native behavior).
But when I apply a style, for example an empty one like this:

```
TextArea {
    style: TextAreaStyle { }
}
```

I can not select text using the android handles as I can when not using any Style. How can I adjust my TextArea using a style and still get the handles?

Comment: What properties exactly did you want to change?

Comment: I wanted to restyle the complete appearance of the textinput.

Comment: You're out of luck then. I am having the same issue though. If you override the style you lose all of the defaults and native look.

Comment: Well, at least I know that it is not just me :-)